# Cannot access URL

Tags: java, json, url

I'm building an app that retrieve JSON from URL.
At first, I used emulator, and connect with URL on localhost. (It works perfectly)
and then I want to access the URL from external server. Now there is the problem.

The logcat always like this:

```
05-17 15:36:48.049: W/System.err(330): java.net.UnknownHostException: culigui.16mb.com
05-17 15:36:48.049: W/System.err(330):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
05-17 15:36:48.049: W/System.err(330):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-17 15:36:48.059: W/System.err(330):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at last.project.CuliGUI.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:30)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at last.project.CuliGUI.MenuPromotion.onCreate(MenuPromotion.java:54)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 15:36:48.069: W/System.err(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-17 15:36:48.080: W/System.err(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 15:36:48.080: W/System.err(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 15:36:48.080: W/System.err(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-17 15:36:48.080: W/System.err(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-17 15:36:48.080: W/System.err(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 15:36:48.080: E/Buffer Error(330): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 15:36:48.089: E/JSON Parser(330): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-17 15:36:48.089: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
05-17 15:36:48.099: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{last.project.CuliGUI/last.project.CuliGUI.MenuPromotion}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at last.project.CuliGUI.MenuPromotion.onCreate(MenuPromotion.java:58)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 15:36:48.118: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

I noticed that there is a problem with java.net.UnknownHostException. I've read some article about it but honestly I didn't understand.

This is my activity, in case some of you need it:

```
// connect to external server
private static String url = "http://culigui.16mb.com/getdataresto.php";

ListView Listview;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_view_all);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSONArray of listresto
        JSONArray  listresto = json.getJSONArray("listresto");

        // looping through All listresto
        for(int i = 0; i < listresto.length(); i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject list = listresto.getJSONObject(i);

            // insert String to Local Variable
            map.put("KEY_ID", list.getString("id_resto"));
            map.put("KEY_NAME", list.getString("nama_resto"));
            map.put("KEY_ADDRESS", list.getString("alamat_resto"));
            map.put("KEY_THUMB", list.getString("thumb_img"));
            map.put("KEY_ABOUT", list.getString("about_resto"));
            map.put("KEY_PHONE", list.getString("no_telp"));
            map.put("KEY_LAT", list.getString("loc_lat"));
            map.put("KEY_LONG", list.getString("loc_long"));
            userList.add(map);

            //for checking value
            //System.out.println("output: " +map);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */

    //this is new custom adapter
    Listview = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, userList); 
    Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it simply can't get to that URL from the machine it's running on. Can you browse  to the URL on the external server that is running the application?

To troubleshoot:

- Ensure you can access the URL from an external machine of a different network to the one you are currently connected.
- If working, check that the device/emulator you are using can access the same URL, if not - then you have a problem with the proxy that the emulator is using (they should normally route through the same network connection used by the host OS).
- If the device/emulator is failing, then try switching it to a different network, or review their own help documentation.